# Error in ajax retrieving data

Tags: ajax

I wanted to retrieve data using ajax, when open the url in browser it showing data but when i execute this url in ajax code error msg function is running however data is showing in browser.
url: "http://live.nayatel.com/?json=1"

```
      $(document).ready(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://live.nayatel.com/?json=1",
                cache: false,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            });

    });
```

its a wordpress site and i used a plugin to retrive its data working in browser but not giving response text.

Comment: how do you mean by execute the data ?

Comment: when i run this code error function is executing but in browser i can see all data in above url

Comment: Does `onSuccess` depend on the returned data?

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `onSuccess`?

Comment: What error is reported? If you don't know that, your error function should use an alert or send the error to console.log so you can see the error.

Comment: i have 2 domains. when i give url : http://creatives.pk/demos/live/?json=1 its onSuccess function is running but when i m giving the url http://live.nayatel.com/?json=1 its error function is executing however both url is working when run them into browser and showing the response text.

Comment: i am just doing alert in both of function function onSuccess(data, status)
        {
  
   alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));   }

Comment: error just showing response text nothing and status showing error...

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions, since I am not that sure about your problem.

a) Try changing

```
success: onSuccess,
```

to

```
success: function(data, status) {
             onSuccess(data, status);
         },
```

b) If that fails, try adding

```
crossDomain: true,
```